# Is it possible to update navigational properties without round trip to database in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a User object that holds Roles navigational property.

```
  public partial class User
  {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ServiceAreaId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
  }
```

I can update the simple properties without reading the entity from the database as described in http://www.shawnmclean.com/blog/2011/04/entity-framework-deleteupdate-without-round-trip-to-the-database/

```
    public User UpdateUser(User user, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<User, object>>> properties)
    {

            context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            context.Users.Attach(user);
            foreach (var selector in properties)
            {
                string propertyName = Utils.GetMemberInfoFromExpression(selector.Body);
                context.Entry(user).Property(propertyName).IsModified = true;   
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

        return user;
    }
```

However I am not sure how or if I can do this for Roles navigational property. When I tried got an "The entity type Collection`1 is not part of the model for the current context." exception.
Thanks.